# Angular 2: how to pass attributes to child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

In my application I have Home as root component and another generic component named as list which i'm rendering inside Home.

I want to pass data as property to my list component which is coming from XMLHttpRequest.

**home.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {DashboardService} from '../../services/dashboard';
import {List} from '../contact/list';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: 
     `
     <h3>Home</h3>
     <List type="{{type}}"></List>
     `
  providers: [DashboardService],
  directives: [List],
})
export class Home {

  private _type: any;

  constructor(private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {
    this._dashboardService.typeToDisplay()
      .subscribe((type) => {
          this._type = type;
      });
  }
}
```

**List.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'List',
  properties: ['type'],
  template: `
        <h2>list</h3>
  `,
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
export class List {

  private type: any;

  constructor(@Attribute('type') type:string) {
    this.type = type;
    console.log(type);
  }
}
```

I'm getting string data from typeToDisplay() method its an Http request & assigning to type variable. but when I passed as property to list component I'm getting null in List constructor.

I tried  too but i'm getting "type" string same way.

Hope my question is Clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This syntax

```
<List type="{{type}}"></List>
```

is setting a property not an attribute.
To set an attribute use either

```
<List attr.type="{{type}}"></List>
```

or

```
<List [attr.type]="type"></List>
```

If you just want to have the value available in `List` use

```
@Input() type: any;
```

instead of the attribute injection.
This way the value is not availabe yet inside the constructor, only in `ngOnInit()` or later.

Comment: Docs are work in progress. Angular is still work in progress. Writing docs before software is developed usually doesn't fly ;-). Also check the code-docs in the source code. A lot of classes have quite comprehensive documentation and links to running examples in Plunker.

Comment: For me i was not needed the prefix ".attr". thank u

Comment: @Adir `.attr` is mainly required it you need it to show up in HTML or if it can only be added to HTML because there is no property with this name on the HTML element or any Angular component or directive on that element.